# TableView is not updating when using Tab bar to pass between two view controllers

Tags: ios, swift

I have a first InputViewController where I gather data from the user
I have a 2nd DisplayViewController with a TableView that display the user info
When adding on InputViewController new user info and switching to DisplayViewController the TableView is not directly updated. Strangely it updates my TableView only if I go back to an initial welcome viewController and go to DisplayViewController via the Tab bar.

I have tried many things without success. I read on several questions that simply below code should be sufficient - what I implemented but it works as described no direct update. Can someone help here I spent already hours to try to fix it without success?

For info, CoreData is working well (info saved and fetched at each entry), so it shouldn't come from this.

```swift
import UIKit
import CoreData

class DisplayViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var ArrayDateOfInputs = DateOfInputs.all

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot it solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

I put the answer here for others who have the same question

```
class DisplayViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

        @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

        var ArrayDateOfInputs = DateOfInputs.all

        override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillAppear(animated)
            tableView.dataSource = self
            tableview.delegate = self
            tableView.reloadData()
    }
```